# QRunnable trying to abort a task

Tags: multithreading, qt

Is it possible to abort a QRunnable task?

I can't find any way to do it even in the documentation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot abort a QRunnable task.

The only way to dirty-abort a thread in Qt is through `QThread::terminate()` (which is discouraged).

`QThreadPool` uses `QThread` behind-the-scenes to run QRunnable tasks, but it doesn't provide a way for developers to call `QThread::terminate()`. Therefore, QRunnable cannot be aborted.

I recommend redesigning your application -- refer to [Multithreading Technologies in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) to get an overview of all the ways you can use threads, and select a solution that matches your use case.

Comment: Is this still true in 2019?

Comment: @arrowd Yes, it's still true in 2019. Think of it this way: A QRunnable task is simply a C++ function, and you cannot **abort** a C++ function halfway. However, you can write extra logic into your function to allow it to **return** before it finishes its task: `if (abortEverythingNow) { return; }`

Answer (score 3):

Qt shares a thread object model similar to many other frameworks (the .NET languages and Java come to mind). In these type of frameworks, it is generally discouraged to try to "abort" a thread. Other threading implementations (like POSIX) are largely the same way. It's bad practice to dirty-kill a thread.

Instead, construct your logic inside run() in such a way that you can put "checkpoints" in every so often to determine if the run() function can safely terminate. These checkpoints should check a flag (or some other sentinel) that indicates that the thread should end.

Comment: You are absolutely right.. but I need to modify an existing application (Marble) which uses those tasks and I thought I could stop them easily